# Ubuntu 18.04 disable WIFI auto login

Tags: 18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and want to disable the **WIFI** auto-login that makes the 30 years old browser randomly pop up regardless of what I'm doing.

It doesn't save the username and password so I still have to use Chrome to log in anyway, It's just annoying - especially when I'm playing games that don't require internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable it, go to `System Settings > Privacy > Network Connectivity Checking` and turn it Off

[image]

Source: [Disable hotspot login Ubuntu 18.04](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/03/disable-hotspot-login-on-ubuntu-1710-and-1804.html?m=1)